# schema registry can't start. NoSuchFieldError: PASSWORD

Tags: apache-kafka

I can't start schema registry and kafka rest. When I use `kafka-rest-start` then exception is occurred:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PASSWORD
```

nowhere can I find what that means.

EDIT

The exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PASSWORD
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryConfig.baseSchemaRegistryConfigDef(SchemaRegistryConfig.java:316)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryConfig.<clinit>(SchemaRegistryConfig.java:310)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain.main(SchemaRegistryMain.java:41)
```

`schema-registry.properties` contents:

```
listeners=http://0.0.0.0:8081
host.name=weuconn1
avro.compatibility.level=backward
debug=false
kafkastore.connection.url=weukaf1:2181,weukaf2:2181,weukaf3:2181
kafkastore.topic=_schemas
kafkastore.topic.replication.factor=2
```

Comment: How are you deploying this? Standalone or part of Confluent Platform download? Which version?

Comment: as standalone service from confluence platform. Newest version

Comment: @RobinMoffatt upgraded from 3.3 to 4.0 and now seeing the same error :/

Comment: I have no SSL and have no idea what this `PASSWORD` is refering to

Comment: Faaar from ideal, but it seems, that recreating VM and installing SchemaRegistry fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a jar mismatch. I got this error but then when I updated the version of confluent-common installed as well, it went away.

Comment: Please be more specific in `updated the version of confluent-common` (to which version?) to make this answer helpful to others. [Edit] and paste your updated POM excerpt.